# ElasticSearch 5.6 > 7.x Upgrade, is there an auto_generate_phrase_query Equivalant?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm upgrading my codebase's ElasticSearch from 5.6 to 7.x due to some features I'd like to explore.

I'm currently using GoLang & "github.com/olivere/elastic/v5" specifically.

However, auto_generate_phrase_query has been depreciated, and AutoGeneratePhraseQueries no longer works on v7 ("github.com/olivere/elastic/v7").

I've read to use explicit quoted queries, what is the equivalent to that in olivere? is there no setting i can set to true/false in ES when making requests to achieve this? Must i explicitly wrap my queries in quotation marks? Surely there must be a proper way to do this...

I found this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

which states `use [type=phrase] instead`

In Olivere, i can set this via: `Type("phrase")`; is this a sufficient alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing was actually using Phrase Queries. For anyone in the future coming back to find an answer.